# RSync backup of Subversion repository with Rsyncrypto

Tags: backup, svn, rsync

*This is a crosspost from stackoverflow because I find that I might get a much qualified audience here*

**The Situation**

I have a pretty large Subversion repository that I am trying to backup efficiently. The repository size is about 6 GB and growing. Some large commits are around 500 to 1GB in size.

I am trying to backup this repository to an off-site location, through an Internet up-link.

**Explaining the sheer size of it**

> To whomever is wondering, the whole production environment for various sites (config files, EXEs, data files) is kept in this one repository so that we can rollback to an existing working version and track the changes to the production setup. Code is kept on a different repository.

**The How**

Here is what I am actually doing:

1. Backup of the repository to a working folder on the server using the **"svnadmin hotcopy SRCDIR TGTDIR"**
2. Encrypt and compress that repository using **"rsyncrypto -r SRCPATH DSTPATH KEYSPATH CERTIFICATE"**
3. Backup that encrypted version to an off-site location using **"rsync -Crtv"** (actually cwRsync because I am running on Windows)

**The Problem**

First I have to say that it works, though it still has an underlying issue.

The problem lies with the fact that I was expecting that each time the process would run, only the **new** revision files/data would be copied ([repos]/db/revs/0/...) thus requiring only bandwidth and time when a large commit is made. However, instead:

- If I run only step #3 many times, rsync behaves as it should and nothing is copied because nothing has changed.
- If I run only steps #2 & #3 many times, rsync also behaves well. The envrypted version is the same everytime and rsync doesn't have to transmit anything.
- But, it seems that every time I run **all three steps** (with a new commit having been made to the repository) the whole repository is being **re-uploaded in full**. Thus, defeating the whole purpose of using rsync in the first place.

It is as though the files in [repos]/db/revs/0/... are changing everytime I make a hotcopy.

**The Questions**

Is this an expected behavior from "svnadmin hotcopy" that the [repos]/db/revs/0/... are changing from one hotcopy to another?

Any suggestion or options I could use to make this hotcopy **rsync friendly** or say **rsyncable**?

I am not quite sure that the use of 'svnadmin dump' on the whole repository would produce an **"rsyncable" file**.

Comment: Can you edit your post to link to the stackoverflow question so we can monitor answers?

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3667259/rsync-backup-of-subversion-repository-with-rsyncrypto

Answer (score 0):

When you encrypt/compress the repository any small change to the underlying data (the repository) is spread throughout the encrypted/compressed file(s). So, a one byte change can propagate across the entire encrypted/compressed data set. So, from rsync's perspective, everything DID change.

Comment: Actually NO. That is the whole purpose of rsyncrypto. It does work its encryption in blocks and if something changes at the beginning it will propagate on only one block length and the rest of the file will stay same. This provides a slight less secure encryption at the benefit of a rsync friendly encrypted file.

Comment: You are correct, now that I looked into Rsyncrypto more.

Comment: And even better, rsyncrypto automatically does file compression using gzip --rsyncable option, which also compress using a block size. Thus, large files becomes encrypted and smaller before transmission. If I can just manage to have similar looking files in the first place, for: subversion, exchange backup, TFS backup, SQL backups, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Files in `db/revs/` are not changing, but their timestamps do.  `--size-only` could be the answer.